# Blazor Server - Large Page Weight

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I've noticed in my blazor server applications that sometimes the page weight can get bloated.

For example, I have a page with a long list, each list item has many components. When I inspect the page in dev tools and save the html as text, the saved file might be 500kb in size. When I inspect the websocket connection and watch the messages, the message that returns the html for the page might be 1000kb or larger. I'm thinking this has something to do with javascript that is injected but am unsure.

Has anyone else noticed this and found solutions?

---- Update ----

It was pointed out I didn't provide sample code, good point! Here's the razor code in question, _itemsSorted could be up to 1000 items.

```
@foreach (var item in _itemsSorted)
{
    <div class="rounded d-flex flex-row justify-content-between @GetItemCssClasses(item)" id="rank_@item.Rank">
        <div>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                @item.Text
                @if (item.Attributes.HasAttribute(Constants.item_Category))
                {
                    string categoryName = GetCategoryDisplayName(Convert.ToInt32(item.Attributes.GetAttributeValue(Constants.item_Category)));
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryName))
                    {
                        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="badge badge-default badge-small">@categoryName</span>
                    }
                }
                @if (!item.Active)
                {
                    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="badge badge-warning badge-small">Inactive</span>
                }
                @if (item.Attributes.HasAttribute(Constants.Ignore) && item.Attributes.GetAttributeValue(Constants.Ignore) == "1")
                {
                    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="badge badge-danger badge-small">Ignore</span>
                }
            </div>

            @if (item.itemType != itemTypes.Folder && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.SubText))
            {
                <div class="text-muted">
                    @item.SubText
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="text-nowrap ml-2">
  
            <button class="@GetButtonsCssClasses(item)" title="@moveUpTitle" @onclick="@(e=> MoveUp(item))" disabled="@moveUpDisabled"><span class="fas fa-arrow-up"></span></button>
            <button class="@GetButtonsCssClasses(item)" title="@moveDownTitle" @onclick="@(e=> MoveDown(item))" disabled="@moveDownDisabled"><span class="fas fa-arrow-down"></span></button>
            <button class="@GetButtonsCssClasses(item)" title="Move to a new location" @onclick="@(e=> ShowMoveModal(item))" disabled="@_savingMoveStarted"><span class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></span></button>
            <button class="@GetButtonsCssClasses(item)" title="Edit this item" @onclick="@(e=> ShowEdititemModal(item))" disabled="@_savingMoveStarted"><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></button>
            @if (!_photoListInUse)
            {
                <button class="@GetButtonsCssClasses(item)" title="Delete this item" @onclick="@(e => ShowConfirmDeleteitemModal(item))" disabled="@_savingMoveStarted"><span class="fas fa-trash"></span></button>
            }
            <div class="d-inline">
                <button class="@GetButtonsCssClasses(item)" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Add new item" disabled="@_savingMoveStarted"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span></button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu pl-2 font-weight-normal" style="width:200px;">
                    @if (showAddFolderAbove)
                    {
                        <a href="" @onclick:preventDefault @onclick="@(e=> ShowInsertItemModal(item, itemTypes.Folder, false, false))" class="text-dark px-2 py-1 d-block"><span class="fas fa-folder-plus"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Insert <b>folder</b> above</a>
                    }
                    @if (showAddSubfolderAbove)
                    {
                        <a href="" @onclick:preventDefault @onclick="@(e=> ShowInsertItemModal(item, itemTypes.Folder, true, false))" class="text-dark px-2 py-1 d-block"><span class="fas fa-folder-plus"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Insert <b>subfolder</b> above</a>
                    }
                    @if (showAddPhotoAbove)
                    {
                        <a href="" @onclick:preventDefault @onclick="@(e=> ShowInsertItemModal(item, itemTypes.Photo, false, false))" class="text-dark px-2 py-1 d-block"><span class="fas fa-image"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Insert <b>photo</b> above</a>
                    }
                    <hr />
                    @if (showAddFolderBelow)
                    {
                        <a href="" @onclick:preventDefault @onclick="@(e=> ShowInsertItemModal(item, itemTypes.Folder, false, true))" class="text-dark px-2 py-1 d-block"><span class="fas fa-folder-plus"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Insert <b>folder</b> below</a>
                    }
                    @if (showAddSubfolderBelow)
                    {
                        <a href="" @onclick:preventDefault @onclick="@(e=> ShowInsertItemModal(item, itemTypes.Folder, true, true))" class="text-dark px-2 py-1 d-block"><span class="fas fa-folder-plus"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Insert <b>subfolder</b> below</a>
                    }
                    @if (showAddPhotoBelow)
                    {
                        <a href="" @onclick:preventDefault @onclick="@(e=> ShowInsertItemModal(item, itemTypes.Photo, false, true))" class="text-dark px-2 py-1 d-block"><span class="fas fa-image"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Insert <b>photo</b> below</a>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-inline">
                <button type="button" class="@GetButtonsCssClasses(item)" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Additional settings"><span class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></span></button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu pl-2" style="width:200px;">
                    <div class="h6">Categories</div>
                    <a href="" @onclick="@(e=> ShowSelectCategoryModal(item))" @onclick:preventDefault class="text-dark px-2 py-1 d-block font-weight-normal" title="Categorize"><span class="fas fa-list text-dark"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Categorize</a>
                    <a href="" @onclick="@(e=> RemoveCategoryFromItem(item))" @onclick:preventDefault class="text-dark px-2 py-1 d-block font-weight-normal" title="Uncategorize"><span class="ion ion-md-close text-dark"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Uncategorize</a>
                    @if (PlType == ePlTypes.Package.ToInt32() || PlType == PlsViewModel.SiteOwnerPlTypeValue)
                    {
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <div class="h6 pt-2">Closeout Settings</div>
                        <a href="" @onclick="@(e=> Exclude(item, true))" @onclick:preventDefault class="text-dark px-2 py-1 d-block font-weight-normal" title="Exclude."><span class="fas fa-ban text-dark"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Exclude</a>
                        <a href="" @onclick="@(e=> Exclude(item, false))" @onclick:preventDefault class="text-dark px-2 py-1 d-block font-weight-normal" title="Include."><span class="fas fa-check-circle text-dark"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Include</a>
                    }
                    @if (item.itemType == itemTypes.Folder)
                    {
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

                        <a href="" @onclick="@(e=> ShowDuplicateFolderModal(item))" @onclick:preventDefault class="text-dark px-2 py-1 d-block font-weight-normal" title="Duplicate Folder."><span class="fas fa-copy text-dark"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Duplicate Folder</a>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Comment: While the "static" page may only be 500kb, the amount of SignalR traffic will depend on how you have written your code to build an update the page.  Heavy traffic is often a sign that something is wrong in the page design.  Without any code, it's difficult to other than speculate.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, good point, I added some sample razor. Since I've started using Blazor one thing I've had trouble finding is what constitutes "good" page design.

Comment: There is Virtualize component exactly for this. It will render only visible items of a long list

Comment: This question is too vague - you should try to create a simple reproducible sample.

Comment: @Liero, the virtualize component is a great call, that significantly improves page performance. Only downside is I have a "table of contents" type of navigation so users can quickly jump between sections of the long list. Unfortunately the virtualize component breaks this because the elements further down the list (or up the list if you're out the bottom) haven't been rendered yet. I tried to use FocusAsync() but that doesn't work either, same issue,

Comment: @Liero, I was able to refactor one of the most problematic pages to use the virtualize component, what a difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown the logic for getting `_itemsSorted` which may be the root cause of your problems. From what you've shown, you can use `@key` to help the renderer identify items in a loop and not re-render them unnecessarily

```
@foreach (var item in _itemsSorted)
{
    <div class="rounded d-flex flex-row justify-content-between @GetItemCssClasses(item)" id="rank_@item.Rank" @key=item>
```

On form design, consider using components for any repeated render blocks.  For example links with @if could be refactored into a component something similar to this:

ConditionalLinkControl.razor

```
@if (Show)
{
    <a href="" @onclick:preventDefault @onclick="e=> this.OnClickEvent(1)" class="text-dark px-2 py-1 d-block"><span class="fas @this.IconClass"></span>@this.Label</a>
}

@code {

    [Parameter] public bool Show { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> OnClick { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string IconClass { get; set; } = "fa-folder-plus";

    [Parameter] public MarkupString Label { get; set; }

    private void OnClickEvent(int item)
    {
        if (this.OnClick.HasDelegate)
            this.OnClick.InvokeAsync(item);
    }
}
```

which you then use as:

```
<ConditionalLinkControl Show"@ShowFolderAbove" OnClick="LinkEventHandler"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm curious about using components for repeated render blocks. This does seem like better design from a code perspective, but does it help with performance?